# toggle divs, but only have one shown at once

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have some thumbnails that slideToggle a hidden div. I only want one to stay open at once though. So when the next thumbnail is clicked, the open div closes and then the new one opens.

I was doing this with show and hide, but it looks bad because I loose the animation from slideToggle.

So what's the best way to hide all toggled divs and then open the new one?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="rowOne">
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneLeftImage" />
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneMiddleImage" />
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneRightImage"/>
  </div>

  <div id="rowOneLeftImageHidden">
      This is information for the left image in the first row.
  </div>

  <div id="rowOneMiddleImageHidden">
      This is information for the middle image in the first row.
  </div> 

   <div id="rowOneRightImageHidden">
      This is information for the right image in the first row.
  </div>
```

and the Jquery to Toggle (But multiple divs can be opened with this...):

```
$('#rowOneLeftImage').click(function(){
        $("#rowOneLeftImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#rowOneMiddleImage').click(function(){
        $("#rowOneMiddleImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#rowOneRightImage').click(function(){
        $("#rowOneRightImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a class on all the expandable divs, say, `expandable`.

```
<div id="rowOneLeftImageHidden" class="expandable">
  This is information for the left image in the first row.
</div>

<div id="rowOneMiddleImageHidden" class="expandable">
  This is information for the middle image in the first row.
</div> 

<div id="rowOneRightImageHidden" class="expandable">
  This is information for the right image in the first row.
</div>
```

You can collapse all of them by referencing the class now, and using slideUp() and slideDown().

```
$('#rowOneLeftImage').click(function(){
    $(".expandable").slideUp();
    $("#rowOneLeftImageHidden").slideDown();
});
$('#rowOneMiddleImage').click(function(){
    $(".expandable").slideUp();
    $("#rowOneMiddleImageHidden").slideDown();
});
$('#rowOneRightImage').click(function(){
    $(".expandable").slideUp();
    $("#rowOneRightImageHidden").slideDown();
```

You could probably avoid all this duplicate code with a little creative use of data- elements, like having the images include a data-target element with the id the div you want them to expand, then you wouldn't need to write n functions for n images.

To wait until they close before opening you can use a delay, or you can do

```
$(".expandable").slideUp(function () {
    // this is called once the animation completes
    if ($(this).is("#rowOneLeftImageHidden")) {
        $(this).slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works well, but would there be a way for the entire div to close and then open back up again? Right now the div doesn't close all the way and the content swaps out and the div starts to open again. It doesn't look very smooth.

Comment: Thanks! I put a delay on the slideDown, and it gives the slideUp time to complete so it looks smooth.

Comment: If you want them to all close before you open the one, you can put that into the callback of slideUp(). However you'll need to be a little careful because the callback is called once for each element animating - in this case, 3 times. So in the callback you'll need to check the id of `this`. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give like items a common class name. This allows attaching handlers to the whole collection at one time

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="rowOne">
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneLeftImage"   class="image"/>
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneMiddleImage"   class="image" />
  <img src="IllinoisLottery_Thumbnail_Taller.jpg" id="rowOneRightImage"   class="image"/>
  </div>

  <div id="rowOneLeftImageHidden" class="image_text">
      This is information for the left image in the first row.
  </div>

  <div id="rowOneMiddleImageHidden" class="image_text">
      This is information for the middle image in the first row.
  </div> 

   <div id="rowOneRightImageHidden" class="image_text">
      This is information for the right image in the first row.
  </div
```

JS:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
        /* get index position of image*/                   
        var index=$(this).index();
        /* slide up visible text, slide down text matching image indesx*/
        $('.image_text:visible,.image_text:eq('+idx+')').slideToggle()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but this is the best I can do to help you with my limited Javascript/JQuery knowledge.

```
function setVisibility(id) {
 if (document.getElementById('btnHide').value == 'Hide div') {
     document.getElementById('btnHide').value  = 'Show div';
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
 } else {
     document.getElementById('btnHide').value  = 'Hide div';
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
 }
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" id="btnHide"    Value="Hide div" onClick="setVisibility('div_name')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you're wanting

```
$('#rowOneLeftImage').click(function(){
        if($('#rowOneMiddleImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneMiddleImageHidden").slideToggle();
        if($('#rowOneRightImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneRightImageHidden").slideToggle();
        $("#rowOneLeftImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#rowOneMiddleImage').click(function(){
        if($('#rowOneLeftImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneLeftImageHidden").slideToggle();
        if($('#rowOneRightImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneRightImageHidden").slideToggle();
        $("#rowOneMiddleImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#rowOneRightImage').click(function(){
        if($('#rowOneMiddleImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneMiddleImageHidden").slideToggle();
        if($('#rowOneLeftImage').is(":visible"))
            $("#rowOneLeftImageHidden").slideToggle();
        $("#rowOneRightImageHidden").slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let someone else do the work for you!

It sounds like you're looking for a "carousel" type display, and there are [bajillions of free plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html) for that.  Or, if you just want a "tabs" effect, I'd recommend [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).  You'll have to learn to use whatever plugin you choose, but most are pretty simple to get started with, and end up producing better results with less work on your part.

Hope that helps!